# Beginner @Rails: undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass and Couldn't find Decision with 'id'=edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For your context: This is my first attempt to create a app. I have just started coding:-).

I am trying to get a simple CRUD setup to work.

Now i'm having two problems i can't get my head around:

1. My entries don't show up on my index page. it gives te following error: 'undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass'. The model contains the following columns: 
   string :title,text :forecast, date :review_date
2. If i go to decisions/edit it gives me the following error: 'Couldn't find Decision with 'id'=edit'

This is my code:

Controller:

```
  class DecisionsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_decision, only: [:show, :edit, :update]

  def index
# gets all rows from decision table and puts it in @decision variable
    @decisions = Decision.all
  end

  def show
# find only the decision entry that has the id defined in params[:id]
    @decision = Decision.find(params["id"])
  end
# shows the form for creating a entry
  def new
    @decision = Decision.new
  end
# creates the entry
  def create
    @decision = Decision.new(decision_params)
      if @decision.save
        redirect_to @decision
      else
        render 'new'
      end
  end
# shows the form for editing a entry
  def edit
      @decision = Decision.find(params["id"])
  end
# updates the entry
  def update
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private
  def find_decision
      @decision = Decision.find(params["id"])
  end

  def decision_params
    params.require(:decision).permit(:title, :forecast, :review_date)
  end

end
```

index view

```
<h1>Hello World ^^</h1>

<% @decisions.each do |descision| %>
 <p><%= @decision.title %></p>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :decisions
  root 'decisions#index'
end
```

I have been working on these two all morning but i can't figure it out. I would be a great help if you guys can take a look for me.

Comment: `decisions/edit` matches `decisions/id` so it goes to the show action. Url should be `decisions/some_id/edit`

Comment: replace `<% @decisions.each do |descision| %>` with `<% @decisions.each do |decision| %>` and `<p><%= @decision.title %></p>`
with  `<p><%= decision.title %></p>`

Comment: Facepalm.. Thx @apneadiving. Both problems are fixed.

What i don't understand is why i shouldn't use the @ symbol for the <p><%= decision.title %></p> part. On the show view it seems to be needed. Can you explain the difference to me?

Comment: `@` is for instance variables: created in the controller and shared in the view. Whenever you write `do |decision|` you create a local variable in the block of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have just started coding

Welcome!!

---

> My `entries` don't show up on my index page.

I'm sure you mean `decisions`, right?

If so, you have to remember that if you're calling a *loop* in Ruby, you'll need some conditional logic to determine if it's actually populated with any data before trying to invoke it:

```
#app/views/decisions/index.html.erb
<% if @decisions.any? %>
   <% @decisions.each do |decision| %>
      <%= content_tag :p, decision.title %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This will have to be matched by the appropriate controller code:

```
#app/controllers/decisions_controller.rb
class DecisionsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_decision, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
       @decisions = Decision.all
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
       @decision = Decision.new
    end

    def create
       @decision = Decision.new decision_params
       @decision.save ? redirect_to(@decision) : render('new')
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
    end

    def destroy
    end

    private
    def find_decision
        @decision = Decision.find params["id"]
    end

    def decision_params
      params.require(:decision).permit(:title, :forecast, :review_date)
    end
end
```

This will give you the ability to call `@decisions` and `@decision` in your views depending on which route you're accessing.

An important point is that when you say...

> `decisions/edit` it gives me the following error: `Couldn't find Decision with 'id'=edit'`

... the issue is caused by the way in which [Rails routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) is handled:

[image]

Because Ruby/Rails is [*object orientated*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), each set of routes corresponds to either a *collection* of objects, or a *member* object. This is why routes such as `edit` require an "id" to be passed - they're designed to work on *member objects*.

As such, when you access *any* "member" route (`decisions/:id`, `decisions/:id/edit`), you'll have to provide an `id` so that Rails can pull the appropriate record from the db:

```
#app/views/decisions/index.html.erb
<% if @decisions.any? %>
   <% @decisions.each do |descision| %>
      <%= link_to "Edit #{decision.title}", decision_edit_path(decision) %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I can explain a lot more - the above should work for you for now.

Comment: Great answer, Rich. When I started learning to code answers like yours inspired me to go on.

Comment: Great answer! But do you care .... instance on each loop is "|descision|" instead of "|decision|" !

Comment: Thanks Mohamad, great to hear! Hope you're doing well!